# Working with the github js api : cant filter issues

Tags: javascript, github, coffeescript

I run these lines using https://github.com/michael/github which is a wrapper for [the GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues)

```
issues.list
  label: "high",
  (err, issues) ->
    createTable issues
```

It keeps listing all of the issues and not the ones with the label "high"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just The answer, don't use that API .. Here's a functional JQuery

```
$.ajax
  beforeSend: (request) ->
    request.setRequestHeader "Authorization", """token #{settings.token}"""
  url: """https://api.github.com/repos/#{settings.user}/#{settings.repo}/issues?labels=high"""
  dataType: "json"
  success: (data) ->
    console.log data[0].title
```